# Ensuring Child Component Reloads When Parent Component Changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on creating an updated implementation of an existing react native app and am running into a situation where a child component doesn't re-load when the parent component changes.

My situation is this: I have a parent component for a particular record. Connected to this is a `VisitTimer` child component that keeps track of duration for a that record's session. What I'm noticing is that, when I load a record into the parent component for the first time, the child component `<VisitTimer>` does fire with `componentDidMount()`. However, if exit that screen, and load a DIFFERENT record, then the child `<VisitTimer>` component does not mount - i.e. `componentDidMount` in the `VisitTimer` child component does not fire.

What is the likely issue here? And how can I ensure that a child component always re-mounts when the parent component changes?

Here is the child component within the parent:

```
  <VisitTimer
    started={this.props?.session?.dates?.started?.value}
    stopped={this.props?.session?.dates?.completed?.value}
    durationOverride={this.props?.session?.duration?.total?.value}
    maxDuration={maxVisitTime(this.props?.session?.type?.value)}
    visit={this.props?.session}
    ref={(ref) => (this.visitTimer = ref)}
    stopTimeOffset={this.props.visit?.duration?.stopOffset?.value}
    editable={statusCodeToEditableLevel(this.props.session?.status?.value) === 2}
    onChange={this.onSessionTimerChange}
  />
```

Comment: This is by design. `didMount` is only when the component first mounts. `didUpdate` will be called instead if the component is still mounted -- and it probably is depending on router setup. You need to implement `didUpdate` in `VisitTimer` -- unless its third party? Let me know.

Comment: The reason its still mounted is because react-navigation, which i assume you are using, will stack screens on top of each other. It doesn't actually unload them: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/

Comment: I see. Just out of curiosity, is there a way I can force it to? That might make my implementation simpler. In other words, if I navigate away from the parent component, unmount the child component?

Comment: Yes. Does the `session` object (which I assume is the "record") have a unique id?

Comment: Yes, it does. There is a unique guid property for every record.

Comment: I will post an answer give me a couple of min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments but a way to force this to be recreated is to give it a unique `key` based on the record. In react, `key` is special, and if it changes the whole component will remount. You could set the key to a unique id from the record:

```
  <VisitTimer
    key={this.props?.session?.guid}
    started={this.props?.session?.dates?.started?.value}
    stopped={this.props?.session?.dates?.completed?.value}
    durationOverride={this.props?.session?.duration?.total?.value}
    maxDuration={maxVisitTime(this.props?.session?.type?.value)}
    visit={this.props?.session}
    ref={(ref) => (this.visitTimer = ref)}
    stopTimeOffset={this.props.visit?.duration?.stopOffset?.value}
    editable={statusCodeToEditableLevel(this.props.session?.status?.value) === 2}
    onChange={this.onSessionTimerChange}
  />
```

I made an assumption the unique id is on `session.guid`.

By the way, this is generally a good idea over implementing `componentDidUpdate` in your situation. People often go that route and spend loads of time implementing reset behavior to set the state back to its original values, which is a source of bugs. Changing `key` guarantees you have a fresh start. The only time you shouldn't do this to achieve a "reset" on a component is if remounting it and its children are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `key` will force a re-render but that's not the primary purpose of key. React docs do talk about using the key like this but those are for specific use cases. In this case I would encourage to ask ourselves:

- Do we really need to re-mount the child component or do we just want it to re-render
- Regardless of the answer to the above question. Why do we need the child component to re-render. Is it because it needs to show an updated data?
- If yes, then the child component should receive a prop from the parent or something from a global state which changes (in your case probably the record itself). That kind of prop change/state change will automatically trigger a re-render

I hope this is helpful but the community can be even more helpful if you can share more details of your problem like - What does the parent component do, what does the child render, why do we want the child to re-render, etc

Comment: This is all very true and provides more context to my answer. I kind of assumed in his use case it'd be ok because it looks like it has no children and is doing something probably mundane about timing out the users session. But more context is needed to be sure. Since its about session, I'm guessing also when it updates, what he actually wants is a state reset, and if the situation allows it, using key for this can be better since you don't need to maintain error-prone manual reset code. But yeh its a lot of assumptions. Stack overflow definitely doesn't have enough focus on the use cases.